# NuGet: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.5.2.3' already exists in folder Install failed. Rolling back

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package

I've formatted my PC and cloned my (previously working) project from the git repo.

I've tried to reinstall packages:

`PM> update-package -reinstall`

It tried to install many packages, but got an error at `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.5.2.3`:

```
Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.5.2.3' already exists in folder 'C:\Users\can\Source\Repos\MyProject\MyProject\packages'
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.2.3' does not exist in project 'Web'
```

Then after executing more commands, I get:

```
update-package : Failed to add reference to 'System.Net.Http'. Please make sure that it is in the Global Assembly Cache.
At line:1 char:1
+ update-package -reinstall
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Update-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.UpdatePackageCommand
```

I've tried deleting the local cache but no avail. I've updated all the packages from the GUI in Visual Studio (Manage NuGet Packages). If I try to build my solution anyway, I get this for two projects (and the solution fails to build):

```
This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer.
Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.
For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105.
The missing file is ..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets.
```

What am I doing wring?

Comment: If reinstall error persists after following below answer, would you mind sharing us the project.json file of the error project Or share us a sample to reproduce this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> If I try to build my solution anyway, I get this for two projects (and the solution fails to build)

That is because the relative path of Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21 is not correct, **need to edit the .csproj file and correct the relative path**. Or **remove the following code from .csproj file**:

```
  <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
<PropertyGroup>
  <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
</PropertyGroup>
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets'))" />
```

and then did `update-package -reinstall`.

Besides, for the reinstall error:

You make sure all packages are restored. Then use the command `update-package -reinstall -Project projectname` to reinstall packages for each project in the solution.

Comment: I broke all the package linkage when I created new web api 2 + mvc 5 projects in my solution and changed the folder names.  This answer brought me directly to the solution and it worked exactly as expected.

Comment: this didn't solve my problem. after further investigation, I've downloaded `nuget.exe`, then installed all packages to my solutin by providing the path for packages explicitly as `..\packages` (of course, relative to my project paths). the problem was that directory didn't exist but VS/NuGet was looking for packages in that non-existent directory, and it was failing. explicitly downloading all packages back to that directory solved the issue. it was probably my gitignore which ignored the packages folder altogether, which caused my solution to build on the older machine which had the folder.

Comment: @Can Poyrazoğl, Glad to know that you have resolved your issue, you can also share your workaround as answer which is benefit to other communities who has the same problem. Thanks.